# css carousel with buttons not working

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

I'm trying to create a css carousel without using javascript. 
The carousel contains buttons to change the current image,
but there are 2 problems with this code.

1.Everything seems to work fine, but when i add a animation to the div (img-
    container) the buttons does not work.

2.How to style the label now so that they will look like radio buttons, placing radio buttons inside them makes the label useless.

what am i doing wrong and what are the other ways to achieve this?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      transition: all 0.2s;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .slider,
    .image-container,
    .sliding-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .slideMove {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .select-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .slider {
      /*height: auto;*/
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .slideMove {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .image-container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-size: 0;
      animation: slide 10s infinite alternate;
    }
    
    @keyframes slide {
      10%,
      30% {
        transform: translate(0);
      }
      32%,
      52% {
        transform: translate(-100%);
      }
      54%,
      74% {
        transform: translate(-200%);
      }
      76%,
      100% {
        transform: translate(-300%);
      }
    }
    
    .img-selector {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .sliding-img {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .slider input:nth-child(1):checked~.image-container {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .slider input:nth-child(2):checked~.image-container {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    
    .slider input:nth-child(3):checked~.image-container {
      transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    
    .slider input:nth-child(4):checked~.image-container {
      transform: translateX(-300%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="select-container">
      <label for='1' class="img-selector">img1</label>
      <label for='2' class="img-selector">img2</label>
      <label for='3' class="img-selector">img3</label>
      <label for='4' class="img-selector">img4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <input id='1' class="slideMove" type="radio" name="slider" />
      <input id='2' class="slideMove" type="radio" name="slider" />
      <input id='3' class="slideMove" type="radio" name="slider" />
      <input id='4' class="slideMove" type="radio" name="slider" />
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="sliding-img" style="background:rgb(20,200,200)">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-img" style="background:rgb(20,20,200)">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-img" style="background:rgb(230,20,200)">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-img" style="background:rgb(10,20,2)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The buttons work but its transition conflicts with the `.img- container` animation. With your html structure, you can start with auto carousel (while no label was clicked) and once the user clicks on any label the auto carousel will stop working.

Comment: is there any way to make them both work?

Comment: No without script, at least not that I can think of.. Why, aren't using one of huge amount of existing carousel plugins?

Comment: Check out http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/ and you can read a bit about it here, about half way down the page: http://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/carousels-dont-have-to-be-complicated/

Answer (score 0):

Just add animation:none to your checked buttons like this:

```
 .slider input:nth-child(1):checked~.image-container {
  animation:none;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, using this the button works but then the animation stops.